# How are parent and child categories related in Craft database?

Tags: categories, database

I am writing an API which directly connects to Craft database and retrieves data.  I need to get the categories hierarchy.  But I can not find how parent and child categories are related in the database, therefore I can't write an SQL query to retrieve it. 
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is there are certain reason why you want to create a custom query rather than using inbuilt functions?

Comment: I am building an api to be used by a third party app and I need to dump all data in json format for the app to be able to use it.  
I got everything done.  This is the only bit I can't figure out.

Comment: That does not really answer my question since you are still able to build the `$criteriaModel` by Craft and convert the `Models` into JSON format. However... see my answer

Comment: I am not that familiar with craft and twig,  so I decided to make an api with php directly interacting with database.

Comment: I see.. Just a suggestion: it's faster to get used to 4-5 lines with Craft than 40 lines of pure PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Craft 2 all information about Parent - Child relations are stored in the `craft_structureelements` table. But it's not like a hierarchy (child has the parent id) so it can be quite confusing at the first moment. 
When you take a look into the `ElementService` you'll see the following how the `getChildren()` parameter from your `ElementCriteriaModel` is converted into a `Query`

```
if ($criteria->descendantOf)
{
    $query->andWhere(
        array('and',
            'structureelements.lft > :descendantOf_lft',
            'structureelements.rgt < :descendantOf_rgt',
            'structureelements.root = :descendantOf_root'
        ),
        array(
            ':descendantOf_lft'  => $criteria->descendantOf->lft,
            ':descendantOf_rgt'  => $criteria->descendantOf->rgt,
            ':descendantOf_root' => $criteria->descendantOf->root
        )
    );

    if ($criteria->descendantDist)
    {
        $query->andWhere('structureelements.level <= :descendantOf_level',
            array(':descendantOf_level' => $criteria->descendantOf->level + $criteria->descendantDist)
        );
    }
}
```

The `ancestorDist` is the `level` of the child. If you only want to have direct children you can ignore that part. `$criteria->descendantOf` is actually the `BaseElementModel` of your current element -> `$element->getChildren` . `$criteria->descendantOf->rgt` is the value in `craft_structureelements` for the certain Id. Imagine `element` is your current element - your `where` could be like

```
WHERE [....] AND (structureelements.lft < element.lft AND structureelements.rgt > element.rgt AND structureelements.root = element.root)
```

And the `getParent()` function will be treated with

```
if ($criteria->ancestorOf)
{
    $query->andWhere(
        array('and',
            'structureelements.lft < :ancestorOf_lft',
            'structureelements.rgt > :ancestorOf_rgt',
            'structureelements.root = :ancestorOf_root'
        ),
        array(
            ':ancestorOf_lft'  => $criteria->ancestorOf->lft,
            ':ancestorOf_rgt'  => $criteria->ancestorOf->rgt,
            ':ancestorOf_root' => $criteria->ancestorOf->root
        )
    );

    if ($criteria->ancestorDist)
    {
        $query->andWhere('structureelements.level >= :ancestorOf_level',
            array(':ancestorOf_level' => $criteria->ancestorOf->level - $criteria->ancestorDist)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, Craft is using the nested set model for storing hierarchy/order for structured elements in the database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model